# Debug grails recompilation

Tags: grails

I am working on grails 2.0.4 project and at some point I've found that recompilation process does not work. Further tries showed that first `run-app` after removing `~/.grails/2.0.4` has recompiling process working well, but running `run-app` next time ignores changes in files during run (no changes on pages and no Compiling… message in log after appears). So my question is how to debug recompilation process?

Comment: When you are running the app the recompile is immediate, you don't need to stop and run again to see the changes. If you run the app and change something (still running), you see the compiling message?

Comment: @SérgioMichels: Maybe I was not clear enough. I know that I don't need to restart application to see the changes (at least in most cases http://grails.org/Auto+Reloading), and this is my problem as auto recompiling works only when running application after removing `~/.grails/2.0.4` if I restart the application it does not work and I don't get compiling message.

Comment: I see now. Are you using some IDE to run Grails or the interactive console?

Comment: @SérgioMichels: I use IntelliJ IDEA, but I use console to run app. Though I've tried to run app IDEA and without even opening it, so this should not be the cause.

Comment: Are you using parameters in the run-app? See: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8951

Comment: @SérgioMichels: no, I run just `grails run-app`. IDEA uses lost of parameters, but I have same problem running without parameters in console.

Answer (score 1):

There's some JIRA issues related to the recompilation:

- http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8951
- http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8573
- http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8914

Only the third one is fixed. Looking in the first, some folks said that this not work:

```
grails run-app
```

But entering in the interactive mode works:

```
grails
run-app
```

Looking a bit in the code, I can see that [GrailsProjectWatcher.java](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-core/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/compiler/GrailsProjectWatcher.java) is responsible for file changes. Try to add debug to the related package and see if you get messages.

Comment: Those JIRA's should be about different bugs as I am using Mac OS X, it is not only about gsp files and I don't use -D params, but I'll try using interactive mode and thank you for linking to GrailsProjectWatcher.

Answer (score 1):

If it's one particular class that's not reloading, one thing you can check is that the package definition is correct. Grails will happily compile a class that is in the wrong package, but this breaks the reloading mechanism.

Comment: This is not the case as no files are reloaded (and on first run reloading is working). Also IDEA tells me if something is wrong with package definition.